# Room Database migration code getting executed every time I open app

Tags: android, android-room

I am migrating from version 16 to version 17 in my database. But Whenever I open the application, The migration code gets executed. **I am not even getting error or any exception.**

Have tried to print the log statements after each query, all logs statements are getting printed.

And There is no error in SQL queries, I have tried executing those separately, Have tried commenting out the queries in the migration logic.  Still facing the same problem.
Please help. Thanks in advance.

This is my Migration code.

```
private val MIGRATION_16_17: Migration = object : Migration(16, 17) {
            override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS beneficiary_meta_details")
                database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS beneficiary_details (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, beneficiaryRefId TEXT , beneficiaryInstrumentRefId TEXT, status TEXT, instrumentType TEXT, displayName TEXT, image TEXT, lastTxnTimeStamp INTEGER, lastTransactionAmount REAL, transactionCategory TEXT, vpa TEXT, bankingName TEXT, mobileNo TEXT, custId TEXT, nickName TEXT, accountRefId TEXT, accountNumber TEXT, maskedAccountNumber TEXT, ifsc TEXT, bankName TEXT, state TEXT, appLocalBeneficiaryName TEXT, appLocalBeneficiaryImageUrl TEXT)")
                database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE configuration_table ADD COLUMN refreshNumber INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0")
            }
        }
```

And these are my corresponding data classes

```
@Entity(tableName = "beneficiary_details")
data class BeneficiaryDetailModel(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) @ColumnInfo(name = "id") var id: Long = 0L,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "beneficiaryRefId") var beneficiaryRefId: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "beneficiaryInstrumentRefId") var beneficiaryInstrumentRefId: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "status") var status: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "instrumentType") var instrumentType: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "displayName") var displayName: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "image") var image: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "lastTxnTimeStamp") var lastTxnTimeStamp: Long?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "lastTransactionAmount") var lastTransactionAmount: Float?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "transactionCategory") var transactionCategory : String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "vpa") var vpa: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "bankingName") var bankingName: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "mobileNo") var mobileNo: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "custId") var custId: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "nickName") var nickName: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "accountRefId") var accountRefId: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "accountNumber") var accountNumber: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "maskedAccountNumber") var maskedAccountNumber: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "ifsc") var ifsc: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "bankName") var bankName: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "state") var state: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "appLocalBeneficiaryName") var appLocalBeneficiaryName: String?=null,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "appLocalBeneficiaryImageUrl") var appLocalBeneficiaryImageUrl: String?=null
)
```

and

```
@Entity(tableName = "configuration_table", indices = [androidx.room.Index(value = ["type"], unique = true)])
data class Configuration (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) @ColumnInfo(name = "id") var id: Long = 0L,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "timestamp") var timestamp: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "type") var type: Int?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "fallbackEnabled") var fallbackEnabled: Boolean?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "refreshNumber") var refreshNumber: Int
)
```

Answer (score 1):

> But Whenever I open the application, The migration code gets executed.

You don't say how you know this to be the case.

The code you have provided works as expected (as is shown below).

It is highly unlikely that the migration is actually being invoked and somehow reverting so that upon another run it is run again.

Often issues with the Migration not apparently running is due to a misunderstanding about exactly when the database migration occur, this being dependant upon an actual request for access to the database and the database being opened.

More specifically getting an instance of the Built database does not open the the database. Rather an attempt has to be made to access the database before it is opened.

e.g.

```
db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this) /* Does not open the database and therefore Migrate */
theDao = getTheDao() /* Only gets the Dao instance, does not open the database */
```

It is not until:-

```
var whatever = theDao.doSomething()
```

That the database will be opened.

**This is perhaps what your issue is.** If so just accessing the data via one of the functions in the class annotated with @Dao will open the dataabase. Alternately you could force an open e.g. `db.openHelper.writableDatabase /* Force database open */`

**If not then I would suggest adding some debugging.**

***Note that the following is based upon and tested according to your code***

- As you are dropping the beneficial_meta_detail table the replacement beneficial_details table was used as the basis *(i.e. the columns in the meta_details is irrelevant as they get dropped)*
- set a const for the Database version e.g.

  ```
    const val DATABASE_VERSION = 16
    @Database(entities = [BeneficiaryMetaDetailsModel::class,Configuration::class], exportSchema = false, version = DATABASE_VERSION)
  ```
- note this has been taken from an example/test where version 16 is built to then migrate to 17
- add the function (this on it's own does nothing):-

  ```
    @SuppressLint("Range")
    private fun showDBInfo(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
        Log.d("DBVERSIONINFO","Actual Database Version is ${db.version}, Build Version is ${DATABASE_VERSION}")
        val csr = db.query("SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE name NOT LIKE 'sqlite_%' AND name NOT LIKE 'room_%' AND name NOT LIKE 'android_%'")
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            Log.d("DBSCHEMA",csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("sql")))
        }
    }
  ```
- amend **`MIGRATION_16_17`** to include a call to the new function
  **`showDBInfo`** e.g.

  ```
    private val MIGRATION_16_17: Migration = object : Migration(16, 17) {
        override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            showDBInfo(database)
            database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS beneficiary_meta_details")
            database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS beneficiary_details (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, beneficiaryRefId TEXT , beneficiaryInstrumentRefId TEXT, status TEXT, instrumentType TEXT, displayName TEXT, image TEXT, lastTxnTimeStamp INTEGER, lastTransactionAmount REAL, transactionCategory TEXT, vpa TEXT, bankingName TEXT, mobileNo TEXT, custId TEXT, nickName TEXT, accountRefId TEXT, accountNumber TEXT, maskedAccountNumber TEXT, ifsc TEXT, bankName TEXT, state TEXT, appLocalBeneficiaryName TEXT, appLocalBeneficiaryImageUrl TEXT)")
            database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE configuration_table ADD COLUMN refreshNumber INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0")
        }
    }
  ```
- optional, but suggested, add a CallBack that will invoke the **`showDBInfo`** when the respective function is invoked e.g. :-

  ```
    private object cb: Callback() {
        override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            super.onCreate(db)
            Log.d("DBCALLBACK","onCreate CallBack Invoked")
            showDBInfo(db)
        }

        override fun onOpen(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            super.onOpen(db)
            Log.d("DBCALLBACK","onOpen CallBack Invoked")
            showDBInfo(db)
        }

        override fun onDestructiveMigration(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            super.onDestructiveMigration(db)
            Log.d("DBCALLBACK","onDestructive CallBack Invoked")
            showDBInfo(db)
        }
    }
  ```
- amend the databaseBuilder to include the CallBack :-

  ```
                .addMigrations(MIGRATION_16_17)
                .addCallback(cb)
                .build()
  ```

Now if you run the App then the log would include :-

```
D/DBVERSIONINFO: Actual Database Version is 16, Build Version is 17
D/DBSCHEMA: CREATE TABLE `beneficiary_meta_details` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, `beneficiaryRefId` TEXT, `beneficiaryInstrumentRefId` TEXT, `status` TEXT, `instrumentType` TEXT, `displayName` TEXT, `image` TEXT, `lastTxnTimeStamp` INTEGER, `lastTransactionAmount` REAL, `transactionCategory` TEXT, `vpa` TEXT, `bankingName` TEXT, `mobileNo` TEXT, `custId` TEXT, `nickName` TEXT, `accountRefId` TEXT, `accountNumber` TEXT, `maskedAccountNumber` TEXT, `ifsc` TEXT, `bankName` TEXT, `state` TEXT, `appLocalBeneficiaryName` TEXT, `appLocalBeneficiaryImageUrl` TEXT)
D/DBSCHEMA: CREATE TABLE `configuration_table` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, `timestamp` INTEGER NOT NULL, `type` INTEGER, `fallbackEnabled` INTEGER)
D/DBSCHEMA: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `index_configuration_table_type` ON `configuration_table` (`type`)
D/DBCALLBACK: onOpen CallBack Invoked
D/DBVERSIONINFO: Actual Database Version is 17, Build Version is 17
D/DBSCHEMA: CREATE TABLE `configuration_table` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, `timestamp` INTEGER NOT NULL, `type` INTEGER, `fallbackEnabled` INTEGER, refreshNumber INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0)
D/DBSCHEMA: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `index_configuration_table_type` ON `configuration_table` (`type`)
D/DBSCHEMA: CREATE TABLE beneficiary_details (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, beneficiaryRefId TEXT , beneficiaryInstrumentRefId TEXT, status TEXT, instrumentType TEXT, displayName TEXT, image TEXT, lastTxnTimeStamp INTEGER, lastTransactionAmount REAL, transactionCategory TEXT, vpa TEXT, bankingName TEXT, mobileNo TEXT, custId TEXT, nickName TEXT, accountRefId TEXT, accountNumber TEXT, maskedAccountNumber TEXT, ifsc TEXT, bankName TEXT, state TEXT, appLocalBeneficiaryName TEXT, appLocalBeneficiaryImageUrl TEXT)
```

- Noting that when the Migration is called (first 4 lines) that the database version is 16 AND that when the onOpen callback is called that the database version is 17.

On a subsequent run (whilst still at version 17) you would get :-

```
D/DBCALLBACK: onOpen CallBack Invoked
D/DBVERSIONINFO: Actual Database Version is 17, Build Version is 17
D/DBSCHEMA: CREATE TABLE `configuration_table` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, `timestamp` INTEGER NOT NULL, `type` INTEGER, `fallbackEnabled` INTEGER, refreshNumber INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0)
D/DBSCHEMA: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `index_configuration_table_type` ON `configuration_table` (`type`)
D/DBSCHEMA: CREATE TABLE beneficiary_details (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, beneficiaryRefId TEXT , beneficiaryInstrumentRefId TEXT, status TEXT, instrumentType TEXT, displayName TEXT, image TEXT, lastTxnTimeStamp INTEGER, lastTransactionAmount REAL, transactionCategory TEXT, vpa TEXT, bankingName TEXT, mobileNo TEXT, custId TEXT, nickName TEXT, accountRefId TEXT, accountNumber TEXT, maskedAccountNumber TEXT, ifsc TEXT, bankName TEXT, state TEXT, appLocalBeneficiaryName TEXT, appLocalBeneficiaryImageUrl TEXT)
```

Prior to the migration you would get something like:-

```
D/DBVERSIONINFO: Actual Database Version is 16, Build Version is 16
D/DBSCHEMA: CREATE TABLE `beneficiary_meta_details` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, `beneficiaryRefId` TEXT, `beneficiaryInstrumentRefId` TEXT, `status` TEXT, `instrumentType` TEXT, `displayName` TEXT, `image` TEXT, `lastTxnTimeStamp` INTEGER, `lastTransactionAmount` REAL, `transactionCategory` TEXT, `vpa` TEXT, `bankingName` TEXT, `mobileNo` TEXT, `custId` TEXT, `nickName` TEXT, `accountRefId` TEXT, `accountNumber` TEXT, `maskedAccountNumber` TEXT, `ifsc` TEXT, `bankName` TEXT, `state` TEXT, `appLocalBeneficiaryName` TEXT, `appLocalBeneficiaryImageUrl` TEXT)
D/DBSCHEMA: CREATE TABLE `configuration_table` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, `timestamp` INTEGER NOT NULL, `type` INTEGER, `fallbackEnabled` INTEGER)
D/DBSCHEMA: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `index_configuration_table_type` ON `configuration_table` (`type`)
```